# How can I flush a new refrigerator water filter without a water dispenser?

Tags: ice-maker

My refrigerator has an ice maker only.  I have no water dispenser and therefore can not flush 2-3 gallons of water through a new filter.  Waiting and discarding dirty ice for a day or two until the cubes are clear is ridiculous.   Surely there must be some other way to flush the filter. Possibly a sink faucet adapter…

Any thoughts?

Comment: Why is that ridiculous? It's a bit of an energy waste, but it's certainly not _difficult_. I think you'd find that this is exactly what your product literature suggests. The alternative is as you suspect, but needn't be elaborate--a simple rubber hose might work.

Comment: Well, aside from the fact that the cubes will never be clear.

Comment: Where is the filter?  Is it built into the fridge the way they are when they have water dispensers?  Or did you install one in the line?